# Using stored procedure in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, model-view-controller, ef-database-first

I am quite new to using stored procedures in my mvc application so will appreciate any guidance regarding the question below.

**The Purpose:**
I have a stored procedure that returns the balance amount of a gift card. Basically when the user inputs a card number, it returns all relevant details for that card. Thing is I dont know how to go about accomplishing this on my MVC application.

**What I tried so far:**
The context class:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<string> GetBalance(string cardNumber)
    {
        var cardNumberParameter = cardNumber != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("CardNumber", cardNumber) :
            new ObjectParameter("CardNumber", typeof(string));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<string>("GetBalance", cardNumberParameter);
    }
```

The controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetBalance(string cardNumber)
    {

        var balance = db.GetBalance(cardNumber).ToList();

        return View("GetBalance");

    }
```

The View:

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetBalance", "Cards", FormMethod.Post))
                        {
                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <form role="form">
                                            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                           
                                               
                                           
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                Number of Cards: <input type="text" name="cardNumber"/>
                                            </div>
                                            

                                            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color: #0a9dbd; color: white;" />
                                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color: #0a9dbd; color: white;">Reset</button>

                                            <div>
                                                @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
```

**The stored procedure**

```
    GO

ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[GetBalance]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@CardNumber nvarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
If Not Exists(Select CardID From Cards With (NOLOCK) Where CardNumber = @CardNumber OR (Cards.CardNumber2 = @CardNumber))
Begin
Select 'Invalid Card Number' as Error
END

Select Sum(TotalAmount) as TotalAmount, StoreCustomerName, StoreCustomerISurname, StoreCustomerEmail, StoreCustomerDOB, StoreCustomerAddress, StoreCustomerCity, 
                         StoreCustomerRegion, StoreCustomerCountry, StoreCustomerCel, StoreCustomerDate, StoreCustomerToken, '' as Error, StoreCustomerID, CardNumber, CardStatus,
                         LoyaltyLevelName, LoyaltyLevel, DiscountLevelAmount, DiscountLevelName, GiftCardEnabled, LoyaltyEnabled, StoreCustomerNumber From (
SELECT        0 AS TotalAmount, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerName, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerISurname, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerEmail, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerDOB, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerAddress, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerCity, 
                         StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerRegion, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerCountry, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerCel, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerDate, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerToken, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerID, 
                         Cards.CardNumber, Cards.CardStatus, LoyaltyLevels.LoyaltyLevelName, LoyaltyLevels.LoyaltyLevel, DiscountLevels.DiscountLevelAmount, DiscountLevels.DiscountLevelName, Cards.GiftCardEnabled, Cards.LoyaltyEnabled, StoreCustomerNumber
FROM            StoreCustomers WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
                         Cards WITH (NOLOCK) ON StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerID = Cards.StoreCustomerID INNER JOIN
                         DiscountLevels WITH (NOLOCK) ON Cards.DiscountLevelID = DiscountLevels.DiscountLevelID AND Cards.CustomerID = DiscountLevels.CustomerID  INNER JOIN 
                         LoyaltyLevels WITH (NOLOCK) ON Cards.LoyaltyLevelID = LoyaltyLevels.LoyaltyLevelID AND Cards.CustomerID = LoyaltyLevels.CustomerID
WHERE         (Cards.CardNumber = @CardNumber) OR (Cards.CardNumber2 = @CardNumber) --WHERE        (Cards.CardID = @CardID)
GROUP BY StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerName, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerISurname, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerEmail, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerDOB, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerAddress, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerCity, 
                         StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerRegion, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerCountry, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerCel, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerDate, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerToken, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerID, 
                         Cards.CardNumber, Cards.CardStatus, LoyaltyLevels.LoyaltyLevelName, LoyaltyLevels.LoyaltyLevel, DiscountLevels.DiscountLevelAmount, DiscountLevels.DiscountLevelName,Cards.GiftCardEnabled, Cards.LoyaltyEnabled, StoreCustomerNumber
Union ALL
SELECT        SUM(Sales.SaleTotalAmount) AS TotalAmount, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerName, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerISurname, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerEmail, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerDOB, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerAddress,
                         StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerCity, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerRegion, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerCountry, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerCel, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerDate, 
                         StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerToken, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerID, Cards.CardNumber, Cards.CardStatus, LoyaltyLevels.LoyaltyLevelName, LoyaltyLevels.LoyaltyLevel, DiscountLevels.DiscountLevelAmount, 
                         DiscountLevels.DiscountLevelName, Cards.GiftCardEnabled, Cards.LoyaltyEnabled, StoreCustomerNumber
FROM            StoreCustomers WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
                         Cards WITH (NOLOCK) ON StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerID = Cards.StoreCustomerID INNER JOIN
                         Sales WITH (NOLOCK) ON Cards.CardID = Sales.CardID INNER JOIN
                         LoyaltyLevels WITH (NOLOCK) ON Cards.LoyaltyLevelID = LoyaltyLevels.LoyaltyLevelID AND Cards.CustomerID = LoyaltyLevels.CustomerID  INNER JOIN
                         DiscountLevels WITH (NOLOCK) ON Cards.DiscountLevelID = DiscountLevels.DiscountLevelID AND Cards.CustomerID = DiscountLevels.CustomerID
WHERE         (Cards.CardNumber = @CardNumber) OR (Cards.CardNumber2 = @CardNumber)--WHERE        (Cards.CardID = @CardID)
GROUP BY StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerName, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerISurname, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerEmail, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerDOB, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerAddress, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerCity, 
                         StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerRegion, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerCountry, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerCel, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerDate, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerToken, StoreCustomers.StoreCustomerID, 
                         Cards.CardNumber, Cards.CardStatus, LoyaltyLevels.LoyaltyLevelName, LoyaltyLevels.LoyaltyLevel, DiscountLevels.DiscountLevelAmount, DiscountLevels.DiscountLevelName, Cards.GiftCardEnabled, Cards.LoyaltyEnabled, StoreCustomerNumber

) as x
GROUP BY StoreCustomerName, StoreCustomerISurname, StoreCustomerEmail, StoreCustomerDOB, StoreCustomerAddress, StoreCustomerCity, StoreCustomerRegion, StoreCustomerCountry, StoreCustomerCel, StoreCustomerDate, StoreCustomerToken, StoreCustomerID, 
CardNumber, CardStatus, LoyaltyLevelName, LoyaltyLevel, DiscountLevelAmount, DiscountLevelName, GiftCardEnabled, LoyaltyEnabled, StoreCustomerNumber

END
```

Comment: I did that, didn't work. I did post what I have  tried. Maybe tell me what I should change in there ?

Comment: What didn't work? Did it throw any exception? If so, please post the stack trace. If not, please explain what did not work.

Comment: What do you mean by it didn't work? Did you see any error? Unexpected output?

Comment: Error :Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Cards/GetBalance

Comment: That's not sql server error. When do you get this error? Have you configured proper routes for that?

Comment: Yes, I've added a button in my IndexView to route to the GetBalance view. <a href="@Url.Action("GetBalance", "Cards")" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #0a9dbd; color: white;">Get Card Balance</a>

Comment: So when I click on this GetBalance button , that error results. I had assumed my whole approach to this was wrong. Which is why I posted this, did not explicitly say that I have an SQL error. I hoped someone could view my code and check what I am doing wrong, hence I asked for guidance on what I have already tried.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya , getting this sql server error now : The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'GiftworxModel.Card'. A member of the type, 'CardID', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name. Any idea what's wrong here, sorry. Quite new to programming.

Answer (score 1):

The only method that you've shown in your controller for `GetBalance` is decorated with the `HttpPost` attribute, meaning that it will only respond to requests that are made via POST, i.e. ones that are made by submitting the form that you've shown in the `GetBalance` view, that you can't get to at the moment.

One thing you can do is provide two separate controller methods:

```
public ActionResult GetBalance()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetBalance(string cardNumber)
{
    // Do stuff to retrieve the balance here
    return View("GetBalance");
}
```

Note the fact that the first `GetBalance` method has:

- No attribute decorating it, so it responds to GET requests (like the one from the link/button on your /Index page)
- Doesn't explicitly name the view that it wants to return - this is because the name of the view is implied by the name of the Action, allowing for marginally cleaner code to be written.

Comment: Gosh, don't know how I missed that. This got rid of that error. Thanks :)

Comment: I am now getting this error: The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'GiftworxModel.Card'. A member of the type, 'CardID', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name. Any idea how to solve this

Comment: @Janine, that's an entirely separate question which will have a very different answer. On stackoverflow a "one question per question" model is followed, so please go ahead and ask another question with the issue you're now encountering, along with the minimum of code to recreate it =)

Glad my answer helped with your first issue! =)